# Keep bookmark when formatting with startsection?

Tags: sectioning, bookmarks

I am looking at the following redefined `section` command. All of my sections do not have bookmarks in the resulting PDF file. I don't want to use new command name. How can I keep the bookmarks?

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \@startsection{section}{0}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}*{}
  {
    \large \colorbox{my-gray}{
      \begin{minipage}
        {\textwidth-0.175in}
        {\textbf{#1 }}
      \end{minipage}
    }
  }
}
```

It would be perfect if i can do something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \@startsection{section}{0}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}*{}
  {
    \large \colorbox{my-gray}{
      \begin{minipage}
        {\textwidth-0.175in}
        {<text and format of the section>}
      \end{minipage}
    }
  }
}
```

### Update 20180203: Minimum reproducible example

This is the `minimum.tex` file:

```
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor={url-gray}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=0.25in,nosep}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Author Name},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}


\section{ First Section}
\label{sec:org6d66304}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\section{ Second Section}
\label{sec:org364f276}

\subsection{Sub section 1}
\label{sec:orgee6ac02}
\begin{itemize}
\item Subsec Item 1
\item Subsec Item 2
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Sub section 2}
\label{sec:org3a19fb4}
\begin{itemize}
\item Subsec 2, item 1
\item Subsec 2, item 2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

And this is `mystyle.sty` located in the same directory with `minimum.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb,charter,color,calc,hyperref,titlesec}
\RequirePackage[empty]{fullpage}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{0.5in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.5in}

% <<< other definitions
\definecolor{my-gray}{gray}{0.90}
\definecolor{url-gray}{gray}{0.25}
% >>>

%% Enumerations
\def\labelitemi{--}

%% Section Headings, etc.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\titlebar}{%
\Large\scshape\raggedright
% \colorbox{my-gray}
% \textwidth{-0.175in}
}%

\titleformat{\section} %command
            [block] %shape
            {\titlebar} %format
            %% {\bfseries} %format
            {} %label
            {0pt} %sep
            {} %before-code
            [\titlerule] %after-code

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont}*{}
  {
    \large \colorbox{my-gray}{
      \begin{minipage}
        {\textwidth-0.175in}
        {\textbf{#1}}
      \end{minipage}
    }
  }
}

\titleformat{\subsection} %command
            [block] %shape
            {\bfseries} %format
            {} %label
            {0pt} %sep
            {} %before-code
            [] %after-code

\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{5pt}{0pt}[{0pt}]
```

PDF produced with pdflatex:

```
pdflatex --version                                                                                                                                            git:master*
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

Current output:
[image]
Bookmarks of "First Section" and "Second Section" are missing, as one may see in the screenshot.

Comment: `\@startsection{section}{1}...`

Comment: @egreg The square bracket in `\@startsection{section}[1]` is correct.

Comment: What square bracket? You should change `{0}` with `{1}` in the body of the definition, because hyperref expects sections to be level 1, not 0.

Comment: @egreg Ah yes, my mistake. However, the bookmarks for the sections are still missing on the PDF file after this change.

Comment: What's the purpose to use `\titleformat{\section}` and then redefining `\section`?

Comment: That's my experiment to try getting the same appearance without having to redefine `\section`. Please ignore `\titleformat{\section}` that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always using `\section*`, which is why it doesn't go through.

```
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{\normalfont\biocyberman@formatsection}%
}
\newcommand{\biocyberman@formatsection}[1]{%
    \large \colorbox{my-gray}{%
      \begin{minipage}
        {\textwidth-0.175in}
        {\textbf{#1}}
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

The `\section` command should be defined without arguments; the last argument specified in `\@startsection` should end with a one argument macro for formatting the title.

[image]

With `titlesec`:

```
%% Section Headings, etc.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titleformat{\section} %command
  [block] %shape
  {\large\bfseries} %format
  {} %label
  {0pt} %sep
  {\biocyberman@formatsection} %before-code

\newcommand{\biocyberman@formatsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{my-gray}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth-0.175in}
    \bfseries#1
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\titleformat{\subsection} %command
  [block] %shape
  {\bfseries} %format
  {\thesubsection} %label
  {1em} %sep
  {} %before-code

\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{5pt}{0pt}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Even thought this adds number to the sections, it is easy enough to solve.

Comment: For those wonder how to remove the section numbers, I added this line in the `mystyle.sty`: `\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}`

Comment: @biocyberman You're removing section numbers at *all* levels.

Comment: That's true. What do I do if I want to keep section number of sub*section?

Comment: @biocyberman I added how to do the same with `titlesec`